# Response is different from start url

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm practicing xpath in scrapy shell. The wepage I work on is

http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/more.php?nameid=1&frameid=1&colorid=1

I want to scrapy data in the table. But after I type

```
scrapy shell http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/more.php?nameid=1&frameid=1&colorid=1
```

in Windows cmd, I find that under "Available Scrapy objects," there is

```
[s]   response   <200 http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/more.php?nameid=0>
```

The response url is different from the url I want to work on. The wrong url does not have the data I aim to extract. Any idea why this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired table is located inside an `iframe` - go to the URL from where the `iframe` is loaded:

```
$ scrapy shell http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/hrb_bzbxt/list_hf.php
In [1]: for row in response.xpath("//table[3]//tr[position() > 1]"):
    print row.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").extract()[0]
   ...:  
551626
551617
551616
551614
551612
551611
...
551521
```

In the demo above the contents of the first cell of each table row is printed.